# Get the Date from Datepicker programmatically as Text

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to get a date, which is displayed in an input of the bootstrap ui datepicker as pure text. Therefore I use a span.
Now I want to get the text of the span, but it doesn't work. Actually, I get an `undefined`. Do you have some tips for me?

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="'2020-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />                  
<span ng-model="textDate">{{dt | date:'dd.MM.yyyy' }}</span>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.$watch('dt', function() {        
   var tD = $scope.textDate.value;
   console.log(tD);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inject $filter into your controller/service and extract the date as a string like so

```
$scope.getDate = function() {
return $filter('date')($scope.dt, 'dd.MM.yyyy');
}
```

Plunkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/53XabChcecjuFqKR6uj9?p=info)

Side-note: Assuming that `dt` already has two-way binding, I don't think it's necessary to `$watch` for changes. Instead, you can directly use `$filter('date')($scope.dt, 'dd.MM.yyyy')` where you need the string value.

Answer (score 0):

Angular's ngModel won't work on a span since it is read only. You need some kind of input for two-way-binding with a ng-model. For this you could use a binding to a getter/setter of the model used on the input field. Here is an example:

```
<input type="text" name="userName"
           ng-model="vm.dt"
           ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }" />
<span ng-bind="vm.dt()"></span>
```

By adding `ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }"` will expose the model to a getter/setter which is a function you can simply call on your span. Also I would recommend to use the `controllerAs` syntax to avoid problems with scopes. Notice the `vm` is the alias for the controller around the `input` and `span`.

For more information check the documentation on [ngModel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel).

Comment: Unfortunately It do not work: It get a 'TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null'

Comment: What version of Angular do you use?

Comment: Angular Version 1.3.13